# Dependency injection with Guice for several implementations of same interface

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'd like to try to use Guice in my project, and stucked on simple(from my point of view) problem.

Assume that i have interface

```
public interface TradeService {
        public boolean buy(Player player, ProductID productId);
}
```

which have several implementations with it's dependencies:

```
 public CarsTradeService implements TradeService {
      //...implementation here...
    }

    public BoatsTradeService implements TradeService {
      //...implementation here...
    }

    public AirplanesTradeService implements TradeService {
      //...implementation here...
    }
```

I understand how to configure implementations and provide needed dependencies for them - to do this i need to create guice `"modules"` which will look like

```
public class CarsTradeModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override 
    protected void configure() {
     bind(TradeService.class).to(CarsTradeService.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

And similar modules to rest two services. Ok, modules builded. But later, when i need to inject this implementations to some class - how could i inject exactly needed implementation?

For example, if i need to get instance of `CarsTradeService` - how could i get exactly this instance?

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use annotatedWith and @Named for doing exactly that.

```
bind(TradeService.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("carsTradeService")).to(CarsTradeService.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

And in the class you want to inject this bean you need to use

```
@Inject
@Named("carsTradeService")
private TradeService tradeService;
```

This will inject the exact class you need.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a solution. But what if i need to inject my TradeService into instance of class that wasn't created by Guice? I will need to direct call something like "injector.getInstance(TradeService.class)" How to get exact implemetation in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use guice multi binding. It is a guice extension.

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings

```
@Override
public void configure() {
  Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(),TradeService.class)
  .addBinding()
  .to(CarsTradeService.class);

  Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(),TradeService.class)
  .addBinding()
  .to(BoatsTradeService.class);

  Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(),TradeService.class)
  .addBinding()
  .to(AirplanesTradeService.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats interesting! And how could i get exact instance of TradeService later in class, which wasn't created by Guice?